# How to give access to specific users on network when sharing files without a domain?

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, windows-10-v1803

Since Windows 10 doesn't have the homegroup feature anymore, I can't share folders with specific users on the network. Say, I want to give read privileges to everyone and write privileges to a specific user on the local network.

So how do I do that without a homegroup or domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In a nutshell

Have a dedicated account on the sharing PC, and use that account for authorization from other PCs

#### Prerequisite

Create an account on the sharing PC, give that account the needed privileges in options of the needed folder(s).

And of course you need to have network discovery and sharing enabled. Here's the command to open the right window to enable them.

```
control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter /page Advanced
```

And the PCs **don't have to** be in the same workgroup.

---

#### Answer 1 (Permanent solution)

On another PC add credentials of the created account to credential manager.

```
cmdkey /add:<comp_name> /user:<username> /pass:<password>
```

For the credentials to kick in, you need to sign out.
To use the credentials immediately also do Answer 2.

---

#### Answer 2 (Impermanent solution)

On another PC execute

```
net use \\<comp_name> <password> /user:<username>
```

It might say something about multiple connections: check that the given share is not open in explorer; if the error remains, reboot(or maybe just sing out, and execute the command).

**But do note that this command is only effective for the current session.**

---

And that's it. Now you have system-wide access to all shared folders on the sharing PC with privileges of the given user.

---

#### Note

If you execute the command for a specific folder, it would do same as without specifying the folder.

```
net use \\<comp_name>\<foldername> <password> /user:<username>
```

Though this way you can mount the folder to a drive.

```
net use j: \\<comp_name>\<foldername> <password> /user:<username>
```

But for some reason persistent mounting doesn't work. After rebooting the drive is still there, but it fails to connect to the shared folder giving the error about multiple connections(the one I've mentioned).

```
net use j: \\<comp_name>\<foldername> <password> /user:<username> /persistent:yes
```

To get around it: add the credentials to the credential manager, and call `net use` without credentials.

```
cmdkey /add:<comp_name> /user:<username> /pass:<password>
net use j: \\<comp_name>\<foldername> /persistent:yes
```

That way it automatically picks appropriate account from the credential manager when you access the shared folder. See Answer 1.

Also if you don't have any folder from that computer mounted, command `net use \\<comp_name> <password> /user:<username>` won't fail after subsequent calls. So if you only need access in a script, you can just call it in that script. Though, as I've mentioned, it will fail if the given share is open in explorer.

For further information look in [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11))(but it's not much there, pretty useless)

Comment: It looks like your answer gives access *to a PC,*  but the question asks how to give access ***to a user**.*

Comment: @Scott what are you talking about? It's clearly about creating and using a user account...

Comment: OK, I’ll play your game.  What we have here is too hand-wavy; let’s get specific.  Suppose the network includes computers named "antler", "badger" and "cougar".  On "antler" there is a folder called "Sales", and you want to give user Tom write access to "Sales".  So you create a dummy user "salesman" (with password "sales123") on "antler", and you give the "salesman" account write access to "Sales".  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And then you go to "badger" and type ``cmdkey /add:<comp_name> /user:salesman /pass:sales123``.  (And, as I type this, I see that your instructions are unclear — are we supposed to type `/add:antler` or `/add:badger`?  I ***guess*** `/add:antler` makes more sense.)  How does this benefit Tom?  If it does anything at all, it looks like it gives everybody on "badger" write access to "Sales".  What if Tom logs in on "cougar"?

Comment: @Scott of course `/add:antler`. I honestly don't understand any of your questions.